# Let $X, Y, Z$ be iid. $N (0, 1)$. Find the joint MGF of $(X + 2Y, 3X + 4Z, 5Y + 6Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be iid. $N (0, 1)$. Find the joint MGF of $(X + 2Y, 3X + 4Z, 5Y + 6Z)$

I ended up getting:

$$M_X(s+3t)M_Y(2s+5p)M_Z(t+6p)$$

is this correct>?

Comment: Why don't you show your work? Note that you can write down the MGF explicitly (The MGF of a standard normal is quite well known).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you've made an arithmetic error.  Let $\boldsymbol B = (X+2Y, 3X+4Z, 5Y+6Z)$ and let $\boldsymbol b = (u,v,w)$.  Then $$M_{\boldsymbol B}(\boldsymbol b) = \operatorname{E}[\exp(\boldsymbol b \cdot \boldsymbol B)].$$  Then $$\boldsymbol b \cdot \boldsymbol B = u(X+2Y) + v(3X+4Z) + w(5Y+Z) = (u+3v)X + (2u+5w)Y + (4v+6w)Z,$$ hence $$M_{\boldsymbol B}(u,v,w) = M_X(u+3v) M_Y(2u+5w) M_Z(4v+6w).$$  As $X, Y, Z$ are iid standard normal variables, their MGFs are the same; i.e., $$M_X(t) = M_Y(t) = M_Z(t) = e^{t^2/2},$$ hence $$M_{\boldsymbol B}(u,v,w) = \exp\left(\tfrac{1}{2}((u+3v)^2+(2u+5w)^2+(4v+6w)^2)\right),$$ which I leave to you to simplify.